# Stratum protocol - problem with mining.submit method

Tags: mining-pools, json-rpc, stratum

code was written according to documentation.

I have following lines for submit method

```
submit() {
    // ["<worker.name>", "<jobID>", "<ExtraNonce2>", "<ntime>", "<nonce>"]
    return this.call('mining.submit', [this.worker.name, this.worker.jobId, this.worker.extranonce2, this.worker.ntime, this.worker.extranonce2]);
}
```

According to documentation "When miner find the job which meets requested difficulty, it can submit share to the server" and the result should be following

```
{"error": null, "id": 4, "result": true}
```

But test was failed (result in the image)

[image]

**QUESTION:** Could some one clarify, waht is wrong and how to solve the problem? What does mean "low difficulty"? Why did I get that message?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory: you submitted a share that does not meet the requested difficulty. The pool requires that shares you submit meet a particular difficulty. If your shares do not meet that, then the pool will reject them. The shares that your software is sending to the pool do not meet the pool difficulty.

To fix this, either you are creating the submission incorrectly, or your miners are not mining at the correct difficulty.